# How do I prevent square images that spans 2 columns from pushing the overall height of the row?

Tags: css-grid

Example here: https://springetts.co.uk/test/

I'm having some difficulty figuring out the best way to turn the third image tile into a rectangle without having to change the original image shape.

Here's a mockup of the result I would like:
[screenshot of the third image as a rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpkX7.png)

I've tried a variety of things, but can't seem to figure out an elegant way for it to work nicely and so I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

I've tried adding height:50% to the  in an attempt to crop the  nested inside but that did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this CSS rule somewhere.

```
.page-id-5077 #post-2661 img {
    aspect-ratio: 2/1;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

That will get you pretty close, although you may need to change the aspect ratio slightly to get the height to match the square images in columns 1 and 2, because your rectangle needs to account for the gap between columns 3 and 4. Through experimentation, I found `aspect-ratio: 41/20;` to be fairly accurate.

PS. While in this case you provided a link which enabled me to understand the problem you’re trying to solve, on Stack Overflow it is considered good practice not to rely on links, because they tend to change over time. Better to write questions which are self-contained and therefore can still be useful in ten years’ time. That means including enough code in your question so that we can understand the problem without reference to external links, or better still, including a working Stack Snippet. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Amazing, this works, thank you Brett.

Also noted on your advice about the linking. Thanks for your time in explaining.